# Sending DATE/TIMESTAMP from device to REST service

Tags: android, rest, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to send a date and time to my SQL oracle database through my REST service. However, the field in the SQL database is getting null.

Here is my code to get the date and time:

```
 public void getCurrentDateandTime() throws ParseException {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    currentDateandTime = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    CDAT = dateFormat.parse(currentDateandTime);
}
```

In my REST service, this field is specified as a date datatype, however my the temporal I am using is TIMESTAMP as I want to get the date and time.

When I use postman sending through test data like this:

```
"createdTimestamp": "2018-02-12T09:27:39"
```

It is being received and shown in my SQL database.

Why is the date I am sending from Android receiving null?

Answer (score 0):

Try this buddy:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

And then send this formattedDate string. Make it string type and then parse your string as datetime object. Hope this works. Happy Coding :)

Comment: quite similar to what I have? the thing is I am sending it in a JSON object. My Currentdateandtime is a string version and it is getting the correct format I want.. however when I do the dateformat.parse it is getting a different format?

Comment: So currentdateandtime = "2018-02-14T12:33:15"... I want my CDAT date type field to equal the same???

Comment: Buddy dont parse it just pass string to your json object. Change datatype in your model class to string from Date or Calendar instance.

Comment: but I need to keep it as a date type not stringg

Answer (score 0):

Most REST APIs stick with iso8601 format as a standard.

The java code would be like:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'"); 
df.setTimeZone(tz);
String nowAsISO = df.format(new Date());
```

Then in Oracle to get back is:

```
to_timestamp('2018-02-14T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"')
```